# How to speed up pg_trgm?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pg-trgm

Create  table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.personal
    (
      id bigserial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      first_name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
      last_name character varying(255),
      middle_name character varying(255),
      deleted integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
    );
```

Query:

```
select last_name, first_name, middle_name, similarity(concat_ws(' ', last_name, first_name, middle_name), 'Smit') AS sml
from personal ORDER BY sml DESC LIMIT 100
```

How to speed up this query?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes), the query you are using and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.41.7):

```
CREATE INDEX ON personal USING gist
   ((coalesce(last_name, '')  || ' ' ||
     coalesce(first_name, '') || ' ' ||
     coalesce(middle_name, '')) gist_trgm_ops);
```

It might be faster to query like this:

```
SELECT last_name, first_name, middle_name,
   (coalesce(last_name, '')  || ' ' ||
    coalesce(first_name, '') || ' ' ||
    coalesce(middle_name, '')  <-> 'Smit') AS dist
   FROM personal
   ORDER BY dist LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: Thank you 11.2 secs ->  752 msec.

Comment: for others: concat is not supported here. I use ||